# Kendo UI MVC call javascript nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Suppose :

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
       .Name("gridListCustomers")
       .Columns(gcf =>
       {
           gcf.Bound(c => c.Id).Hidden(true);
           gcf.Bound(c => c.Nom);
       })
       .Events(e => e.Change(???OnChange???)))

     <script>
       (function () {
          function OnChange (){
             //Todo
          }
       })();
     </script>
```

How can I call the nested function only with definition the MVC template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `OnChange` will be availabe only within the closure scope, that is what closures are for.

But you can assign the *change* event in another way, using [`bind()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/widget/methods/bind):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        let grid = $('[name="gridListCustomers"]'); // Not sure if is this the right selector for your grid. Select the grid whatever way you like.

        grid.bind("change", function() {
            // Your chenge function body here
        }
    });
</script>
```